# Restricting input text to numbers only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way to restrict text to nubmers only in an input textfield?
I tried using:

```
myInputText.restrict = "0-9";
```

But it had no effect. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: I just ran a quick test and it works as expected. What issues are you having?

Comment: If what Marcela says is true, tell me what happens when you try restricting letters? Does it work properly?

Comment: You ARE using an INPUT text field, right?

Comment: I am definitely using a text field. It continues as if there were no restrictions put on the input field at all -  all characters are allowed.

Comment: myInputText.restrict only works for text typed by user. But it do not prevent you to set anything via code (myInputText.text = 'abcd' will set "abcd").
Is that your case ?

Comment: No. I entered it via the keyboard rather than actionscript. Thanks though

Comment: As Marcela says - this code works perfectly fine for me. Provide more information about platform, how you export it, version, etc. Upload reproducable version. There are many ways to workaround it, but that's not the point.

Comment: On creating a simplified flash document I found that it also worked for me. After a bit of time trying to find what was wrong with the troubling document, I realised that I had two instances that were sharing the same name - the one that I was trying to restrict and another hidden behind other symbols. I deleted this and the code worked perfectly. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT: My method described below is an alternative to .restrict, and can theoretically allow for much finer control.]

Yes, you can, quite quickly. We're going to combine a Regex and an event listener.

First off, you're going to need to set up an event listener on the text box. I'll call the input box txtInput, for the sake of conversation. This will point to a function we'll write called `validate();`

`txtInput.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, validate);`

Now, we need to create our function.

```
function validate(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    var currentString:String = txtInput.text;       //It is usually easier to work with the textInput contents as a string.
    var numbersRegex:RegExp = /^\d*$/;              //A regular expression accepting zero or more numbers ONLY.
    var invalidRegex:RegExp = /\D+/;                //A regular expression accepting one or more NON-numbers.

    if(numbersRegex.test(currentString) == false)   //Run the test. If it returns false...
    {
        currentString = currentString.replace(invalidRegex, "");    //Removes all non-numbers.
    }
    //Else, we do nothing.

    txtInput.text = currentString;                  //Put the updated string back into the input box.
}
```

(Granted, that code is untested, but it should more or less work.)

The logic going on here: The user enters a character into the box. The event listener fires as soon as the key is pressed. If the string isn't 100% numbers, then the string is searched for all non-number characters, and those characters are removed.

EDIT AS REQUESTED: Also, make sure you don't have conflicting instance names. If you have two input boxes with the same name, Flash may be looking at the wrong one.

`txtInput.text = "Sample text."` should throw a compiler error if there's a duplicate, or in the worst case, show you which input box you ARE affecting.

Comment: I am not familiar with regular expressions but it looks like this should work however, code copied word for word, this has no affect. By any chance does my embedded font have to need to be exported for actionscript for this to work?

Comment: You know, that is a legitimate possibility. Did you update the `txtInput` to the name of your input box? This is working off of a Classic Text Input Box, by the by. It would seem that something is fubar'd in the text box itself...?

Comment: If you could, add some line of code like `txtInput.text = "This is a test.";` where it will run initially. Let me know if the text box actually updates.

Comment: I found the issue while messing around with the document. I wrote about this in a comment on the main question. Your testing would have equally found the issue so I'll give the 50 reputation to you if you turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
myInputText.restrict = "0-9\\-\\^\\\\";
```

Try this, this should work.

Comment: Made no difference unfortunately. Isn't this just the same but with the Hyphen, Backspace and Caret added?

Comment: Ya this is the syntax in action script bro. I don't know why it is not working for you.